# Magento 1.9 get current url

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I want to get Current URL in Magento 1, using observer function, that observer triggered on the AJAX controller action.

In the observer function, I tried like :-

`$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`
it returns the controller action which wee used to call in AJAX, where us I need to get the Current active URL from the browser.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192212/get-current-url-in-magento-and-show-something

Comment: $currentUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentUrl(false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

to

```
$currentUrl = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```